# Error in HttpListenerResponseWrapper: Write failure

Tags: servicestack

I have a self hosted ServiceStack app running in Linux (Centos 6.4) using mono 2.10.8.

I am seeing the following error in my logs intermittently - It is fairly random. Sometimes no errors for a minute or more, sometimes a few errors in quick succession. It doesn't seem to affect the running of my app.

```
ERROR2013-04-24 05:40:23 – Error in HttpListenerResponseWrapper: Write failure
System.IO.IOException: Write failure ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket        has been shut down
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)     [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)  [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.ResponseStream.InternalWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32     count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Net.ResponseStream.Close () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseStreamExtensions.CloseOutputStream (System.Net.HttpListenerResponse response) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I notice in:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/HttpResponseStreamExtensions.cs

there are some tests for running under mono/Fastcgi and it looks like there have been issues with that. Could this be related? Any workarounds for this?